# PyCharm for new comers: create new python file?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am reading the PyCharm quick guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/quick-start-guide.html

I did "Create a project from scratch".

I read the other parts of this page.

But I have no clue what to do next.

I want to code this:

```
print('hello word.')
```

in a file called `hello.py`.

The IDE looks like this at the moment::

[image: pycharm-after-create-project]

Where and how should I create `hello.py` file?

Answer (score 3):

Rightclick on `foo` and you will see `New` menu, hover on it, then click `Python file` and name it `hello`.

Comment: alternatively, **left click** on `foo` and hit `alt + insert`

Answer (score 0):

Press `Alt + Insert`, select `New` from drop-down list, and enter new filename.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- Right click on foo, then new file, then create it
- Since it looks like you're using Ubuntu, use the terminal at the bottom and type `touch hello.py`